# What's the default kernel version that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: kernel, versions

I wish to know the default kernel version that comes with Ubuntu 16.04.6

Answer (score 3):

There are two different kernels that could be seen as 'default' for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with or without HWE enabled).

**For prior releases upgraded & 16.04 & 16.04.1 installs - no HWE (4.4)**

If a system was installed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS install media, or it was an older system upgraded to 16.04 (ie. Ubuntu 15.10 or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release-upgraded to 16.04) then **HWE** is disabled by default and kernel is 4.4.  This of course can be changed by enabling HWE (*default is off for upgrades or <16.04.2 media installs*)

**For later installs with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS or later media - HWE & 4.15**

If the Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS or later media was used for installation, then 4.15 is the default kernel.

*For more information on HWE or hardware enablement stack, see* https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

If your Ubuntu 16.04.6 system was installed with 16.04.6 media then HWE is enabled and you'll be using 4.15.  If however a 16.04.1 or older install media was used; and system fully-upgraded so it reports 16.04.6 you'll only have the 4.4 kernel.  The kernel used by a 16.04.6 system thus depends on install media used, OR if HWE was enabled post-install.

Comment: If you were using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with HWE enabled, I'm not sure if the HWE enabled survives release-upgrade, so it could be the 4.4 kernel on upgrade will get upgraded as to eventually reach 4.15. (*HWE can't be enabled for non-LTS or 15.10 upgrades*)